# SessionMode and InstanceContextMode difference in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am currently studying WCF sessions and after reading few articles on MSDN... one thing that I feel confusing is about Clear Difference between SessionMode and InstanceContextMode that we can use in WCF.

I know the different values that we can use for both these attributes but what exactly is the difference between these two methods?

Why there are these two methods in WCF?

Comment: This is explained quite succinctly, I think, on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.sessionmode(v=vs.110).aspx). Do you have a specific scenario in mind where you are not sure what to use?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a difference between these two methods. The `SessionMode` is a property of the `ServiceContract` attribute. The `ServiceContract` attribute should be applied to interfaces. Whereas the `InstanceContextMode` property is a member of the ServiceBehaviour attribute, which is applied on the actual implementation of a service (class).

So with the `SessionMode` property you define wich type of SessionModes are allowed to be implemented on the actual service. And with the `InstanceContextMode` property you define the actual implemented behaviour of a service.

If the interface is marked with `SessionMode.NotAllowed`

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
public interface IHelloService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello();
}
```

And the class is marked with `InstanceContextMode.PerSession`

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class HelloService : IHelloService
{
    private int _requestCount;
    public string SayHello()
    {
        _requestCount++;

        return $"Hello this is your {_requestCount} request";
    }
}
```

A `System.InvalidOperationException` will be thrown at runtime once you try to host the Service.

**Remark**: A weird thing I experienced. When you mark the interface with `SessionMode.Required` and mark the class with `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`, no exception is thrown and everythink works fine. Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: I suggest you post the last paragraph as a new question. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum so answers should not contain further questions.

Answer (score 0):

While the two values seem similar and in some ways interact, the settings actually control different aspects of the `WCF` service.   The `InstanceContextMode` property is used to control when new service objects are created by the application.  The `SessionMode`, on the other hand, indicates whether sessions are allowed, not allowed, or required.

Some additional links to review:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.sessionmode(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx